# JOOQ, ignore columns like created_date, last_modified_date in INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, jooq

using mysql, can create a column like:

`last_modified_date`    timestamp   default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

So when inserting and updating, we don't need to update this column.

Thought to use readonly column in Jooq:

```
          .withSyntheticObjects(new SyntheticObjectsType().withReadonlyColumns(
            new SyntheticReadonlyColumnType().withTables("*.*").withFields("CREATED_DATE").withFields("LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
          ))
```

The generated class has:

```
public final TableField<BookRecord, LocalDateTime> CREATED_DATE = createField(DSL.name("created_date"), SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME(0).nullable(false), this, "");
```

When trying to use

```
    BooksRecord rec = new BooksRecord();
    rec.from(myPojo);               
    dslContext.batchUpdate([rec]).execute();
```

it will complain created_date is null if we don't set the created_date. same for the modified date.

What's the correct way of using this SyntheticReadonlyColumnType? how do I check if it is working or not?
Is there a way to globally ignore those columns in update and insert sql generation?

Update:
ok, seemed that the SyntheticReadonlyColumnType isn't supported in open source edition: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/readonly-columns

So the question will be what's the best way to achieve this in the open source edition? call Record.reset(Field) everytime before doing update?

Answer (score 1):

> So the question will be what's the best way to achieve this in the open source edition?

The best approach is to use the built-in [readonly column support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-readonly-columns/) of the commercial edition, which handles a lot of caveats and edge cases, including statements that your write manually, not just the CRUD `UpdatableRecord.store()` calls. It also does this automatically for every new computed column that you add to your schema.

> call Record.reset(Field) everytime before doing update?

That's obviously an option, but you'll have to remember it *every* time you intereact with this record type.

If upgrading isn't an option (yet), and your readonly column use-cases are limited to `UpdatableRecord` calls *only*, then you could implement something similar using a [`RecordListener`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/crud-record-listener/), but that won't work for example if you write:

```java
dsl.update(BOOKS).set(rec).where(BOOKS.ID.eq(rec.getId())).execute();
```

The [out-of-the-box readonly column support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/readonly-columns/) can patch that SQL query as well for you, transparently.